# USB Type C RA RB RC

Tags: usb

Can someone please explain what the USB Type C RA RB RC resistors, why are they used? Are these pull downs or pull ups connected to s specific voltage supply?

Comment: USB specs are free to download and read. For what purpose you are asking this?

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/442063/2028

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB-C UFP CC configuration: What Rd resistor value I need to use to be able to draw up to 3A?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/442063/usb-c-ufp-cc-configuration-what-rd-resistor-value-i-need-to-use-to-be-able-to-d)

Comment: The correct designations are Ra, Rp and Rd.

Answer (score 0):

For charging:

Connecting CC1 and CC2 to GND via (usually 5.1k, but not always) resistors will provide up to 3A @5V from a fairly modern USB wall charger.

See figure 4-5 in [USB Type-C Spec R2.0](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf)

Check for the latest version of the official document.

Comment: Not "will" provide. It may or may not provide 3A as it depends if the supply can provide 3A or not. Many supplies will not. And your device may not pull more than what the charger advertizes. I don't think this answers the asked question.